# In multi select drop down I am not able to get the selected values after the spaces in the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("hi");

    $("li").click(function(){

        var favorite = [];

        $("input:checked").each(function() {

            favorite.push(this.value);

    });
```

[image]

please refer the above image to have a overview about the problem I am facing. The related logic I have implemented to get that value of a drop-down is also attached in the snippet. Any help is sincerely thanked.

html code

ticket type

Comment: post your code so that someone can find out what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these:

```js
// This will get the value of the radio buttons:
let favourites = Array.from($('li input[type="checkbox"]:checked')).map(e => $(e).val());
console.log(favourites);

// Grab the innerText of the element
let favourites2 = Array.from($('li')).map(e => ({
    checked: $(e).children('input').is(":checked"),
    text: $(e).text()
  })).filter(e => e.checked)
  .map(e => e.text);
console.log(favourites2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="1" checked/>innertext1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="2" checked/>innertext2</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="3" />innertext3</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="4" />innertext4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But still it does the same thing.

Comment: @jithendrakumar post your html in question

Comment: @jithendrakumar Im assuming you are looking for the `innerText` value of the `<li/>`. I have updated my answer

Comment: I shall share the html portion of it.

Comment: @Miroslav Glamuzina, It works perfectly fine.... Thanks for the help. #million thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad to help